# Bring text to the front of a plot

Tags: matlab, text, rotation, matlab-figure, bringtofront

I have a figure in MATLAB. Then I add a text to it by typing,

```
b = text(0.5, 0.5, 'Detector action', 'Rotation', -70, 'FontSize', 25);
```

But the text goes behind the figure (See below),
[image]

I also tried,

```
uistack(b, 'top');
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try it with `annotation`?

Comment: @Dev-iL No, How?

Comment: You are placing your `text` object in a 3D domain, so depending on your viewpoint there is always a case where it will be _behind_ the graph. Just find the coordinate set `(x,y,z)` which place your text in front of the graph _in the final view_

Comment: @Hoki What do you mean?

Comment: I mean the `text` object is placed in the same 3D domain as the data you plot, so the relative position of your patch and your text matter. It might be better to use [`annotation`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) object as @Dev-iL suggested because they will always be on top of the `axes`, so on top of anything plotted in the figure.

Comment: Yes, but the problem with `annotation` is that it doesn't accept rotation argument.

Comment: How can I rotate the text generated by `annotation`?

Comment: @Dev-iL How can I rotate my text?

Comment: @Mohammad Use an `annotation` of type [`TextArrow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.shape.textarrow-properties.html), which has a `TextRotation` property (instead of `TextBox`, which doesn't) and make the arrow invisible (set (`LineStyle` and `HeadStyle`) and/or `Color` to `none`).

Comment: @Dev-iL Oh great! Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is not to bother with a [`text`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) at all, but instead use an [`annotation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html), since such an object will be (at least by default) above the axes (and thus, anything plotted inside them).

The trick with `annotation` objects, is that counter-intuitively, we need **not** use a `TextBox`, but instead a [`TextArrow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.shape.textarrow-properties.html), while making the arrow itself invisible.

For example:

```
figure(); membrane(); 
annotation('TextArrow', [.5 .5], [.5 .5], 'String','Some text', 'TextRotation', -30, ...
           'HeadStyle','none','TextBackgroundColor','w' );
```

[image]